# Hadoop error stalling job reduce process

Tags: hadoop

I have been running a Hadoop job(word count example) a few times on my two-node cluster setup, and it´s been working fine up until now. I keep getting a RuntimeException which stalls the reduce process at 19%:

```
    2013-04-13 18:45:22,191 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task:attempt_201304131843_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
    2013-04-13 18:45:22,299 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_201304131843_0001_m_000000_0' done.
    2013-04-13 18:45:22,318 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
    2013-04-13 18:45:23,181 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions : org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:255)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:182)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:375)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:461)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:444)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:710)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:443)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.getOwner(RawLocalFileSystem.java:426)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLog.obtainLogDirOwner(TaskLog.java:267)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater.truncateLogs(TaskLogsTruncater.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:260)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:468)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.getOwner(RawLocalFileSystem.java:426)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLog.obtainLogDirOwner(TaskLog.java:267)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater.truncateLogs(TaskLogsTruncater.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:260)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Has anyone any ideas of what might be causing this?

**Edit: Solved it myself.**
If anyone else runs into the same problem, this was caused by the etc/hosts file on the master-node. I hadn´t entered the host-name and address of the slave-node. 
This is how my hosts-file is structured on the master-node:

```
    127.0.0.1   MyUbuntuServer
    192.xxx.x.xx2   master
    192.xxx.x.xx3   MySecondUbuntuServer
    192.xxx.x.xx3   slave
```

Comment: hi, Please post your answer as an answer rather than an edit to the question.  Yes it is ok to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: I suffer from this problem too.  However, my /etc/hosts is okay.  Hence, I don't think this is what solved your problem.

Comment: Same issue as above.  My /etc/hosts is OK.  @avner have you resolved your issue or tried increasing heap size?

Answer (score 0):

a similar problem is described here:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.mahout.user/8898

The info there might be related to other version of hadoop. It says:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to
>   get file permissions : java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/bin/ls": error=12, Not enough space

The solution their was to change heapsize through **mapred.child.java.opts*  *-Xmx1200M**

See also: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cdh-user/BHGYJDNKMGE

HTH,
 Avner