# MarkLogic : Error while importing files using MLCP

Tags: hadoop, marklogic, mlcp

I have tried to import files using MarkLogic content pump in MarkLogic server running in production environment using the following command.

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\mlcp-1.3-3\bin>mlcp.bat import -host localhost -port 8891 -username admin -password admin -mode local -input_file_type archive -input_file_path /d:/NewFolder/
```

The input file path has both the Binary and XML files.

```
"D:\NewFolder\20150626200126+0800-000000-BINARY.zip"
"D:\NewFolder\20150626200126+0800-000001-XML.zip"
```

When i tried to run an import command in command prompt. I got the following response which i am not familiar with.

```
15/06/29 16:53:11 INFO contentpump.ContentPump: Hadoop library version: 2.6.0
15/06/29 16:53:11 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type: XML
15/06/29 16:53:11 ERROR contentpump.ContentPump: Error running a ContentPump job

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions
: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515:
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:
715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:808)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.
loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.
getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus.<init>(LocatedFileStatus.java:
42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedL
istStatus(FileInputFormat.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(File
InputFormat.java:264)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat.getSplits(FileA
ndDirectoryInputFormat.java:80)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ArchiveInputFormat.getSplits(ArchiveInputFo
rmat.java:56)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJobRunner.run(LocalJobRunner.java:128)

    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runJobLocally(ContentPump.java:
307)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runCommand(ContentPump.java:204
)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.main(ContentPump.java:67)

    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.
loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.
getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus.<init>(LocatedFileStatus.java:
42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedL
istStatus(FileInputFormat.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(File
InputFormat.java:264)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat.getSplits(FileA
ndDirectoryInputFormat.java:80)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ArchiveInputFormat.getSplits(ArchiveInputFo
rmat.java:56)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJobRunner.run(LocalJobRunner.java:128)

    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runJobLocally(ContentPump.java:
307)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runCommand(ContentPump.java:204
)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.main(ContentPump.java:67)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file        permissions
: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515:
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:
715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:808)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.
loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.
getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus.<init>(LocatedFileStatus.java:
42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedL
istStatus(FileInputFormat.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(File
InputFormat.java:264)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat.getSplits(FileA
ndDirectoryInputFormat.java:80)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ArchiveInputFormat.getSplits(ArchiveInputFo
rmat.java:56)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJobRunner.run(LocalJobRunner.java:128)

    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runJobLocally(ContentPump.java:
307)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runCommand(ContentPump.java:204
)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.main(ContentPump.java:67)

    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.
loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.
getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus.<init>(LocatedFileStatus.java:
42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedL
istStatus(FileInputFormat.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(File
InputFormat.java:264)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat.getSplits(FileA
ndDirectoryInputFormat.java:80)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ArchiveInputFormat.getSplits(ArchiveInputFo
rmat.java:56)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJobRunner.run(LocalJobRunner.java:128)

    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runJobLocally(ContentPump.java:
307)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runCommand(ContentPump.java:204
)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.main(ContentPump.java:67)
```

Can any one help me on this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Is "/d:/NewFolder/" correct?

Comment: @sss4r ya its correct the above imort command working fine if i run from my local

Comment: Ah, OK, just checking--I've only used mlcp a few times, and that syntax looked unfamiliar to me.

Comment: Which version of MLCP are you using, against which versions of MarkLogic?

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems similar to the one listed here: [Hadoop error stalling job reduce process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990503/hadoop-error-stalling-job-reduce-process)

The resolution there was to increase heap size. Add `-Xmx512m` to an environment variable called `JVM_OPTS`..

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error when doing the MarkLogic University course XQuery II.
The vm they had available for the course was super slow, so I setup my own Windows 7 VM in Parallels.

When I ran this from Unit 6:

    `mlcp.bat import -host localhost -port 8012 -username admin -password admin -input_file_path C:\mls-developer-2\socialmedia\content\enriched -mode local -input_file_pattern "disqus.*\.xml" -output_uri_replace "C:/mls-developer-2/socialmedia/content/enriched, 'socialmedia/disqus'"`

I got the same error you see...
I tried setting _JAVA_OPTIONS to increase the memory available to the JVM as some posts had suggested but that had no effect.

I eventually got the command to work by changing it to:

    `mlcp.bat import -host localhost -port 8012 -username admin -password admin -input_file_path "C:\mls-developer-2\socialmedia\content\enriched\*.xml" -mode local -output_uri_replace "C:/mls-developer-2/socialmedia/content/enriched, 'socialmedia/disqus'"`

There was something about input_file_pattern "disqus.*.xml" that it didn't like. Doesn't look like it's the same thing in your case, but I thought I would post my issue here for others.

Answer (score 0):

Are the input documents the result of exporting content using **MLCP**? That appears to be the purpose of `-input_file_type` archive. If that's not where documents came from, try `-input_file_type documents -input_compressed true`.

Comment: Yes, the input documents are exported using MLCP and it has both the files and metadata and it is exported from different server.

Comment: Is it the same version of MarkLogic in both environments? What version?

Comment: The [Windows MLCP example](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/content-pump#id_56922) in the docs shows "-input_file_path C:\space\bill" -- could you try that instead of "-input_file_path /d:/NewFolder/"? The "Error while running command to get file permissions" suggests MLCP is having trouble finding or reading the input file(s).

Comment: In MLCP docs they also mentioned /c:/gs/import/filename the way that I am used. The strange thing is the import command works well in the server where I am exported.

Comment: Both the environment have Marklogic version 7.x installed

Comment: In the question that grtjn linked to, the asker says he solved it by fixing his hosts file. I remember MLCP being a bit particular about host names. Maybe try using the host's name instead of "localhost".